# Insheet a Specific Variable in Delimited Data in Stata

Tags: stata, csv

I have data in a .txt in which the variables are delimited by the symbol | and the first row contains the variable names.  I have successfully insheeted the data as:

```
insheet using "filename.txt", delim("|") clear
```

However, I would like to insheet only one variable from the data set.  When I try to insheet only the one variable in, I have tried:

```
insheet variable using "filename.txt", delim("|") clear
```

Unfortunately, it does not work, and using a reduced down version of the .txt, I receive an error:

```
too few variables specified
error in line 2 of file
```

The .txt looks as follows:

```
V1|V2
123|456
```

Note that there are more variables and more rows but I've reduced it for ease of exposition.  In addition, the .txt is formatted with an automatic return after each row.

I would greatly appreciate any help that you can provide to do this task.  Please let me know whether there is any further information that I can provide about the to make the issue clearer.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult for me to say why that doesn't work, but `insheet` is old code that seems a little more fragile than other import commands.

Did you try `import excel`?

Is it out of the question to `insheet` everything and `drop` what you don't want?

Did you think of using `filefilter` to change the `|` to spaces or commas?

Comment: Thank you for the comment.  Some of the .txt files are too large for me to figure out how to open in stata.  In any event, I do not need all of the variables in the .txt so I was hoping that I could only insheet the ones that I need.  So in response to your second suggestion, I cannot go that route it seems.  I have never used import or filefilter before so I will look into your first and third suggestion.  Of not, I'm editing the initial post now to reflect what the .txt looks like.

Comment: I am guessing after some experiments that specification of a varlist with `insheet` always requires as many names as there are variables in the file. That is, `insheet` does not allow selective input of just some variables. That's a guess. I think you need to look elsewhere. Alternatively, pre-processing (with Awk, Perl, ...) could strip out the one column you want.

Comment: I guess I'm a little confused because as I wrote above, in other data sets, I've successfully done insheet v1 using "Filename.txt" when I did not need the delimit().  Do you know how such pre-processing might done in perl?

Comment: You did say that. Can you give a reproducible example? Sorry, but I have not written a Perl program for several years.

Comment: You know on second thought I think I am completely mistaken.  I think it was only after I created a successful data set, I then was able to extract a select number of variables with the *use* command.

Comment: did you have a chance to look at the similar question [here](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2012-06/msg00722.html)?

Comment: Good find by Metrics. Supports the interpretation that `insheet` does not support selection.

Answer (score 0):

The Stata command `insheet` does not have this option. Use `insheet` and `keep varname`.